# How to remove "Get Started" button from Facebook bot

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, bots

I know how to add it:

```
{ 
  "get_started":{
    "payload":"get_started_payload"
  }
}
```

But I need to remove it

Comment: I found this, but I don't know how to do it from Postman https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api/#delete

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the way to do it, from Postman

[image: This is how it must be done from Postman]

Comment: Just to clarify this, you include the "persistent_menu" in the example and that is required in order to be allowed to remove the "get_started" button.  Apparently you cannot continue to use a Persistent Menu if you don't have a Get Started button.

Comment: Worked great. I have found that these "bot" tools like manychat, and other services totally bomb your persistent_menu settings, as well as a few other settings that can only be modified by the API.